# Random place in frame

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am developing a small game but I'm stuck on this. I want to generate a random position for an SKSpriteNode called div. I have this code

```
    let random = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.width)
    let random1 = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.height)

    div.position = CGPoint(x: Int(random), y: Int(random1))

    self.addChild(div)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong and why the div is sometimes out of the frame and not visible. Does anyone has a good solution for this?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hint: It is better to use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of the mod "%" operator: `let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width))`

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting this in your `didMoveToView`,

`self.size = view.bounds.size`

Comment: Ha I had that same issue a couple days ago, it was driving me nuts!